# What is the correct way to specify a JavaScript regular expression that will match a period at the end of a line?

Tags: javascript, regex

As I read the documentation a backslash is used to escape a character. So I coded the regular expression as:

```
xxx  = new RegExp("\.$", "g");
```

This does not work and through trial and error I found that

```
new RegExp("\\.$", "g");
```

does work.

Is the documentation incorrect?

Comment: What documentation? And you are using the backslash to correctly encode the period which has a meaning in regex. The "g" is not needed since there can be only one _last_ period in a string

Comment: You've asked nine previous questions. With respect, you should be able to mark up code correctly by now. When you were typing your question, to the right of the text area there was a handy **How to Format** box. Worth a read, as are the various bits of information available from the **[?]** link above the text area.

Comment: my mistake not to include a link:  [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `m` flag to make `$` match end of lines, and escape the `.`:

```
var regex = /\.$/m;
```

or:

```
var regex = new RegExp("\\.$", "m");
```

In a string to get a literal backslash you need to escape it with another backslash.

Comment: Does JS handle m? I thought $ was always the end of a string

Comment: @mplungjan, it does [according to MDM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) at least.

Comment: And perhaps more to the point, according to the spec, [here](http://es5.github.com/#x15.10.7.4) and [here](http://es5.github.com/#x15.10.2.6).

Answer (score 1):

Because you're using a string to initialize the `RegExp` object, there are *two* layers involved: The string, and the regex. Remember that in string literals, `\` has a special meaning, and so to actually put a `\` in a string, it has to be escaped (with another `\`). To actually pass a backslash into the `RegExp` constructor in the string, you have to use `\\` in the string.

This is one of several reasons you're usually better off using a regular expression literal rather than using a string. The literal equivalent of your second code snippet is:

```
xxx = /\.$/g;
```

Comment: i was using regexp because its an easier target to find in a large amount of application code.

Comment: @dan-: You mean, like searching for `RegExp`?